# How to make a discord.js welcome user function?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to use the GuildMemberAdd thingy, and it's not working. I've tried a lot of stack overflow question answers, none work. Can someone help???

My code right now:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    let welcomes = await memeber.guild.channels.fetch('796153454686896208')
    welcomes.send('**' + member.user.username + '** has joined the server!'); 
});
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have intents enabled? You need to check it on.

https://discord.com/developers/applications Go to here and select your bot app and go to the bot tab and scroll down and turn on the intents.

Comment: Yes, `TypeError: member.guild.channels.fetch is not a function`

Comment: Which Discord.js version do you have?

Comment: Oh wait LOL i just fixed it.

Comment: Okay nice to know.

Comment: Instead of typing "member", I typed "**meme**ber"

Comment: Oh, if you typed memeber should've thrown an error saying it is undefined. Either way, you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Here's the code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    let welcomes = await client.channels.fetch('816066665913385032') // get channel
    welcomes.send('**' + member.user.username + '** has joined the server!') // send message
    logging.send('**' + member.user.username + '** has joined the server') // send in logging channel idk
    let role = await member.guild.roles.fetch('800055283962478592') // add member role part 1
    member.roles.add('804163518525210682') // part 2 here
})
```

Sorry about the bad question!!!